# Default menu editor with automatic page list

Tags: menus, functions, php

How can I add a page to the menu and define for the menu item that all subpages should be included by means of a simple checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might be interested in one of my threads. Here: [How to Hard Code Custom menu items](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15455/how-to-hard-code-custom-menu-items/15488#15488)

Thanks!

Comment: You can modify the code to find all the children and add them

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out since this is an old question, but the new menus for WP 3.0+ has a "menus" option that lets you drap a drop pages to form your menus.

The "menus" option also uses a checkbox to determine which pages are included.

HTH

Comment: I am actually looking for a way to add one "page" and have all its children automatically included.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress Menu do not work by automatically generating content. You can use the menu editor to add your pages manually, but menus do not get populated automatically.

So there is nothing in the *Wordpress Frontend Menu API* (undocumented) with which you could achieve what you're asking for.