# How to Hard Code Custom menu items

Tags: menus

Is there any way that i can hard code the custom menu items when first theme installed? I am creating a theme which will automatically make some common pages when installed. So I need to know if I can also add them to Wordpress custom menu so client don't need to add them manually?

In other words: how to insert/create custom menu item programmatically?

Let me know if anything unclear. Guide to the appropriate codex page is welcome. Thanks!

---

**update:** tried code from here [Targeting specific menu with wp_nav_menu_items](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11914/targeting-specific-menu-with-wp-nav-menu-items)

**Menu registration:**

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array('main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu' ) )
  );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

**Template use:**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
```

**Code for adding new items:**

```
function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'main-menu' ){
    $homelink = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __('Home') . '</a></li>';
    $items = $homelink . $items;
    return $items;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items', 10, 2 );
```

when adding the code for adding new items in nav menu in `functions.php` file nothings happens in menu page in admin panel but the current menu items are gone in site!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Problem with your code is that its not actually adding the links to the menu and only to the menu's output, hence the use of a filter (add_filter) so you are just filtering the output of the menu in fact even if you don't have a menu your link will be shown with the code you are using. But to create a link and add it to a menu you can use this code:

```
$run_once = get_option('menu_check');
if (!$run_once){
    //give your menu a name
    $name = 'theme default menu';
    //create the menu
    $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu($name);
    //then get the menu object by its name
    $menu = get_term_by( 'name', $name, 'nav_menu' );

    //then add the actuall link/ menu item and you do this for each item you want to add
    wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array(
        'menu-item-title' =>  __('Home'),
        'menu-item-classes' => 'home',
        'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/' ), 
        'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

    //then you set the wanted theme  location
    $locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');
    $locations['main-menu'] = $menu->term_id;
    set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $locations );

    // then update the menu_check option to make sure this code only runs once
    update_option('menu_check', true);
}
```

I commented all over to make it simpler.

To create a child page/sub page/second level menu (how ever you may call it), you just need to set the `menu-item-parent-id` in the new item for example:

```
//create the top level menu item (home)
$top_menu = wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array( 
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Home'),
    'menu-item-classes' => 'home',
    'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/' ), 
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'
    'menu-item-parent-id' => 0,
    ));
//Sub menu item (first child)
$first_child = wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array( 
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('First_Child'),
    'menu-item-classes' => 'home',
    'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/' ), 
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'
    'menu-item-parent-id' => $top_menu,
    ));
//Sub Sub menu item (first child)
$Second_child = wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array( 
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Second_Child'),
    'menu-item-classes' => 'home',
    'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/' ), 
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'
    'menu-item-parent-id' => $first_child,
    ));
```

also you can set the position by code with `menu-item-position`
and i think its done like this:

- First item - 'menu-item-position' => 1

  - First item first child - 'menu-item-position' => 1
  - First item second child - 'menu-item-position' => 1

    - First item second child first child - 'menu-item-position' => 1
- Second item - 'menu-item-position' => 2
- 3rd item - 'menu-item-position' => 3
- 4th item - 'menu-item-position' => 4

Comment: Those are the functions i was looking for :) codex does not included these :( One more question how can i add a item child to the Home item. I will let you know as soon as i get to my pc. Thanks!

Comment: @Sisir: i updated with an example how to create child pages

Comment: @Bainternet: got this error when first run the code `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp\www\citystir\wp-admin\menu.php on line 25`. But the menu is get created and when page refreshed everything works but nothing is showing in `Appearance -> Menu Theme Location` section. We are really close :) Thanks!

Comment: @Bainternet: My guess is the code is getting error when it trying to run the code `$locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');` So, the codes before that (all the menu insertion is done) get executed and code after that (set the wanted theme  location) don't get executed.

Comment: @Sisir: code is working just fine, what is your theme location name and show me the exact code you are using , i'll see if i can help.

Comment: @Bainternet: Here http://pastebin.com/Px16q43a. Used pastebin.

Comment: @Sisir : what's your menu location name?

Comment: i used this code in nav menu ` wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) );` so i guess the theme location name is `main-menu` right?

Comment: yes but you still need to register this theme location using `register_nav_menu( $location, $description );` before you try to assign a menu to that location.

Comment: @Bainternet : Thanks! the theme location name is now showing. But the error was still there until i put it in a function then add the function in my theme option page. Now it will run only when button clicked. Seems that way the error is gone. Everything is working fine now. Thanks for all your help. I hope you always get to my questions ;)

Comment: Glad you got it.

Comment: @Bainternet: Hi, i had to bother you again :) By function `wp_update_nav_menu_item()` the menu items are adding as custom link. Is there any way where i can add post, page type menu items? It is because now when i am updating my permalink the custom links does not updating. But if it is a page type menu items i would update automatically. I guess i am clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: @Bainternet: Hi, the `menu-item-position` attribute has to be incremental from menu's top item to bottom, no matter if there are any subitems or not. I found this here: http://www.acousticwebdesign.net/wordpress/how-to-create-wordpress-3-navigation-menus-in-your-theme-or-plugin-code/.

Comment: Even 9 years later, still helpful info !

Answer (score 12):

Your original code is **very close** to the money and I seriously think the this long solution by @Bainternet (no offence) is overkill, so have a look at this instead:

```
function new_nav_menu_items($items, $args) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ){
        $homelink = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __('Home') . '</a></li>';
        $items = $homelink . $items;
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items', 10, 2 );
```

Your only problem was that you were not returning **$items** after the function checked for the correct menu, and you were missing the second callback argument that was needed to make the check (*$args*).

Comment: How would you set the location of the menu item using this method?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in Wordpress 3.4.2:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/ae96b842f9f55ecfb22da705a4902b9d25580259#wp-includes/nav-menu.php

You need to create the term relation manually:

```
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object('top menu');
$id = wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, $data);

if ($menu->term_id && (!is_object_in_term($id, 'nav_menu', (int)$menu->term_id))) {
    wp_set_post_terms($id, array((int)$this->id), 'nav_menu');
}
```

See https://gist.github.com/4148529 for an example of the Menu class for simple menu creation.

Answer (score 0):

For information, current user has to got rights to add terms, my menu_items were created but not added in the table wp_terms_relationship before I add a call to wp_set_current_user(1);