# How can I create an auto-populated menu that is automatically assigned to a location?

Tags: menus, buddypress

I'm trying to add BuddyPress nav menu support to my theme and, unfortunately, BP's template tags still aren't fully up to snuff. (Basically, if you're not making an explicit child theme for the BP Default theme, you've got to reinvent several wheels.)

So what I'd like to do is

1. Detect when BP is active (I know how to do this)
2. Register a menu position when BP is active (also a known quantity)
3. Create a default menu containing links to the BP sections (**this is where the hole in my  knowledge exists**)
4. Assign said default menu to the newly-registered position

So, essentially, with my theme active, if a user activates BuddyPress, they'll automatically get a menu with Members, Forums, Activity, etc. and it will be displayed to a position, **but** if users wanted to override the menu, they would be free to do so.
Thoughts?

**EDIT 1**

Bainternet wins the prize. Here's what I did, slightly modified from his solution:

I conditionally registered a menu location

```
if( function_exists( 'bp_get_loggedin_user_nav' ) ){
    register_nav_menu( 'lblgbpmenu', 'Default BuddyPress Menu' );
}
```

I then conditionally hooked in a call to the menu setup

```
if( function_exists( 'bp_get_loggedin_user_nav' ) ){
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'lblg_add_default_buddypress_menu' );
}
```

Then, last of all, I actually registered the menu

```
function lblg_add_default_buddypress_menu(){
    global $lblg_themename;
    $menuname = $lblg_themename . ' BuddyPress Menu';
    $bpmenulocation = 'lblgbpmenu';
    // Does the menu exist already?
    $menu_exists = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menuname );

    // If it doesn't exist, let's create it.
    if( !$menu_exists){
        $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu($menuname);

        // Set up default BuddyPress links and add them to the menu.
        wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' =>  __('Home'),
            'menu-item-classes' => 'home',
            'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/' ), 
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

        wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' =>  __('Activity'),
            'menu-item-classes' => 'activity',
            'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/activity/' ), 
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

        wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' =>  __('Members'),
            'menu-item-classes' => 'members',
            'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/members/' ), 
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

        wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' =>  __('Groups'),
            'menu-item-classes' => 'groups',
            'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/groups/' ), 
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

        wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' =>  __('Forums'),
            'menu-item-classes' => 'forums',
            'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/forums/' ), 
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));

        // Grab the theme locations and assign our newly-created menu
        // to the BuddyPress menu location.
        if( !has_nav_menu( $bpmenulocation ) ){
            $locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');
            $locations[$bpmenulocation] = $menu_id;
            set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $locations );
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: See also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73964 where I mention a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So basically you are asking how to create a custom menu by code and assign it to a menu location:

```
 //give your menu a name
$name = 'theme default menu';
 //create the menu
$menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu($name);
 //then get the menu object by its name
$menu = get_term_by( 'name', $name, 'nav_menu' );
 //then add the actuall link/ menu item and you do this for each item you want to add
wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Home'),
    'menu-item-classes' => 'home',
    'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/' ), 
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));
// you add as many items ass you need with wp_update_nav_menu_item()

//then you set the wanted theme  location
$locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');
$locations['LOCATION_NAME'] = $menu->term_id;
set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $locations );
```

So all you have to do is add as many links as you want, change `LOCATION_NAME` to the actual location name and make sure this code is only run once.

Comment: This, I think, might be along the lines of what I'm looking for.

Comment: This worked out, with modifications. See above, where I've added the solution I ended up using.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `wp_nav_menu()` needs to include a custom callback function, such as a call to `wp_list_pages()`, to which you can pass an `include` argument, into which you can include explicit Page IDs.

Comment: Although if BuddyPress "sections" don't correspond to WP Pages, then my solution won't work. :)

Comment: and it's not really answering the question in hand.

Comment: How does it not answer the question at hand? ZaMoose is asking for a custom-populated menu under specific conditions.

Comment: he is asking how to create a menu, add links to it and set its location. or maybe i got the question wrong.

Comment: Right - and I'm proposing a solution that precludes the need to create a custom menu. The end result is that the correct menu items display in the correct menu locations, under the specific conditions.

Comment: Ok - i see what you mean :)

Comment: Chip:
I'd like to avoid the custom call-back, as I want an actual, editable menu (essentially a skeleton). This would allow people to add/remove from the default BP sections via the Menus GUI. Does that make sense?

Comment: Chip, see above. I think my solution nicely encompasses the functionality.