# Update Theme Location Programatically

Tags: get-theme-mod

I've been trying to update my theme location programmtically and while the menu gets created with menu items, the theme location never gets set.

Here is what I have:

```
function create_my_menu() {
if(!is_nav_menu('primary-menu')) {
  $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu('primary-menu');
  //$menu = array( 'menu-item-type' => 'custom', 'menu-item-url' => get_home_url('/'),'menu-item-title' => 'Home', 'menu-item-status' => 'publish' );
  $menu = get_term_by('name', 'primary-menu', 'nav_menu');
  wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array( 'menu-item-type' => 'custom', 'menu-item-url' => get_home_url('/'),'menu-item-title' => 'Home', 'menu-item-status' => 'publish' ));
//    wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, $menu );
  $locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');
  $locations['primary-menu'] = $menu->term_id.  
  set_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations', $locations);
}
}
```

My menu is registered in my functions file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

function register_my_menu() {
register_nav_menu( 'primary-menu', __( 'Primary Menu' ) );
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm working on a plugin for a multisite setup. I need the menu to be created when a user creates a new site.

I suppose I could modify the default menu that gets created when wordpress is installed.

Comment: Please see my edited answer, based on your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't be (or need to be) "updating" the `theme_location` for a custom nav menu. The `theme_location` is the **template location** for a given nav menu.

If you need to do dynamic manipulation of a custom nav menu, you might be better off targeting the `id` of the menu, rather than the `theme_location`. Your code above seems to be conflating the two. (**Note that `wp_create_nav_menu()` accepts a menu *name* as an argument, rather than a menu *theme location*.**)

But, what are you actually *trying to do* by dynamically manipulating menus in this way? Perhaps we can find a better solution.

**EDIT**

Based on your clarification: you definitely need to target the **Menu Name**, rather than the **Theme Location**.

One Theme Location correlates to one defined (physical) location within the Theme template. A Theme Location is not a *menu* itself, but rather a *marker* to indicate *where a menu is output*.

If you need to generate a default menu (**and I'm really not sure why you need to do this; simply define a proper callback to `wp_nav_menu()` instead**), then you need to pass the **Menu Name** to `wp_create_nav_menu()`.

Answer (score 0):

[How to Hard Code Custom menu items](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15455/how-to-hard-code-custom-menu-items)

The answer here demonstrates how to setup the menu and link it to a menu location.