# Adding PHP in the menu

Tags: php, menus

So, I have following `php` code:

```
<?php global $my_profile; ?>
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) : ?>
    <div class="img" data-key="profile"><?php echo get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 64 ); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It pulls the profile picture of currently logged in user.
I am trying to add this to one of the menu item title, so that user profile picture is shown as a part of the menu.

It looks like I cannot directly add this code into `menu`.

What would be the best way to add this into one of the menu title?

Thanks.

Steve

Comment: You will need something like this: **http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15455/how-to-hard-code-custom-menu-items/60442#60442**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your functions file and use [wp_nav_menu_items](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L386)

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','wpsites_add_avatar_to_nav', 10, 2);
function wpsites_add_avatar_to_nav( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
    return $items;    

    $dude = get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 48 );

    if (is_user_logged_in()) : 
    echo'<li class="your-custom-class right">' . $dude . '</li>';
    endif;

    return $items;
}
```

Might need to use [output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832207).

Some work is required on your behalf to get your code working with this filter. You will need to change the class depending on which theme you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out :

> ```
> <?php global $my_profile; ?>
> <?php if (is_user_logged_in()){
>     $avatar = '<div class="img" data-key="profile">'.get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 64 ).'</div>';
> }else{
>     $avatar = '';  
> }  ?>
> ```

And your menu code should be like this

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'location of menu in your theme',
    'menu'            => 'slug',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'items_wrap'      => $avatar.'<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

Fill all the parameters as per your requirement.
For full list of parameter check this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu