# Call to a member function get_page_permastruct() on null

Tags: plugins, menus

I am trying to add a new menu item to an already existing nav menu in my theme,  I am using some part of this answer [How to Hard Code Custom menu items](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15455/how-to-hard-code-custom-menu-items)

I am directly using this code in my plugin

```
wp_update_nav_menu_item(2, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Home'),
    'menu-item-classes' => 'home',
    'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/' ), 
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));
```

But it gives me following error

> Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 357 of file C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\link-template.php. Please fix and try saving again
>
> Call to a member function get_page_permastruct() on null

Comment: never edit you code from the wordpress "code editor"

Comment: @MarkKaplun Why ? , and where should i edit it then

Comment: Why? because it is extremely insecure practice, and it is easy to make an edit that will break your site without an ability to remove it. Use a proper editor, with an integrated FTP support, or an FTP software that can detect local changes and upload to the server "automagically"

Answer (score 0):

adding it to 'init' action hook works

```
function update_menu_custom(){
wp_update_nav_menu_item(2, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Home'),
    'menu-item-classes' => 'home',
    'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/' ), 
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));
}

add_action('init','update_menu_custom');
```

But it still doesn't works as expected, It adds too many menu items with name home, But that is a different issue

Comment: register_activation_hook

Answer (score 0):

The wp_update_nav_menu_item should be used with register_activation_hook with the following instructions. In your functions.php of your plugin or theme or any other php that it is always executed add:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'addnav_menu_init');


function addnav_menu_init(){
     wp_update_nav_menu_item(2, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  __('Home'),
    'menu-item-classes' => 'home',
    'menu-item-url' => home_url( '/' ), 
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));
}
```

THEN DEACTIVATE AND REACTIVATE THE THEME OR THE PLUGIN in order to add this page to menu, otherwise it does not work.